# Mismatch error of oracle data access in visual studio 2012 asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, oracle, visual-studio-2012, odp.net

I have windows 7 (32 bit) installed in my pc.I installed odp.net in my machine but when i  add reference in visual studio 2012 i got following **error**.

```
Warning 1   There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project
being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference 
"Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.111.7.20, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=534809534051-2,
 processorArchitecture=x86", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures.
```

Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

How can i get rid of this issue ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle.DataAccess mismatch error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638067/oracle-dataaccess-mismatch-error)

Answer (score 1):

It's just a warning.  It's telling that you're compiling with "any CPU" and the referenced dll is fixed at x86 so there's a chance that it won't work if you deploy to an x64 machine without also coping the x64 dll.  See:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14652425/852208